# Euro Symbol not viewed in windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, euro

I am trying to print the Euro Symbol in my Windows forms application with the following code.
It works for all other characters & symbols, but Euro(€) is not displaying.

```
string input = ((char)128).ToString();
Font f = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12f);
Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics();
gr.DrawString(input, f, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
```

128 - is the decimal of Euro sign
Can anyone help on this?

Comment: How or where did you determine that 128 is the correct value for the Euro sign?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid:sorry, I did not get your question.

Comment: Try `string input="\u20A0";` //20AC

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever: http://www.ascii-code.com/
If I give 131, i get that F sign and if I give 130, I get the comma sign, but Euro is not working.

Comment: Try `8364` instead of `128`.

Comment: @Henrik: Thanks ya.. but, What was the reason for using 8364?

Comment: @devouredelysium: I flagged your comment as non-constructive and off-topic. This is a software development page, not one about politics or finance.

Comment: 128 is not €, see http://www.asciitable.com/ for ASCII character codes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

128 isn't the correct value to represent the Euro sign. Maybe try:

```
string input = ((char)0x20AC).ToString();
```

Because `U+20AC` is the Unicode code-point for a Euro sign.

Comment: Thanks friend, but I need the explanation that if I put 130 there, I get that particular symbol and Why no 128?

Comment: @kovilpattiCsharper - from the page you linked to, for 128-255: "There are several different variations of the 8-bit ASCII table. The table below is according to ISO 8859-1, also called ISO Latin-1. Codes 129-159 contain the Microsoft® Windows Latin-1 extended characters." So, there are several different possibilities for the ASCII values. And they don't match unicode, which is what you ought to be using if you want to supply numeric values in .NET.

Comment: Happy with your response. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

By using the below code, I achieved printing Euro symbol without using unicode of it.

```
String input = Encoding.Default.GetString(new byte[] { 128 });
Font f = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12f);
Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics();
gr.DrawString(input, f, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
```

This may help someone.